# How do i load a .swf via a url in html object and/or embed tag?

Tags: flash

I thought this would be simple, but its not working  .. in both the object/embed code, i try to load a .swf via a url but nothing loads.
ex:
name="movie"value="http://localhost/mySite/Flash/Flash.swf"

If i run the pages locally from the flash folder and ref via:
name="movie"value="Flash.swf"
... it works fine

I thought it might be a security issue so i tried to change name="allowScriptAccess" value="always", but that didnt help.

Any help is appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend [SWF Object](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/)

It is easy to use, free, and it also takes care of the annoying "click here to activate this.." issue in IE.

Comment: is 'click to activate this' annoying? =) I use flashblock by choise.

Answer (score 1):

- Solution:
  This was not working because my .swf was referencing a .xml file - in order for it to work propery i had to tell flash where this was, so i had fully quality it in the url as well

ie: old
http://localhost/mySite/Flash/Flash.swf

new:
http://localhost/mySite/Flash/Flash.swf&xml=http://localhost/Flash/Myfile.xml

Answer (score 0):

here is the proper code to embed swf

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="Yourfilename.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> <EMBED src="Yourfilename.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> </OBJECT>
```

then just ensure that you have the MIME settings permit the use of swf files in your web server

please mind the caps tags, i pulled this from an old site

Comment: when using the exact same code above, it does not work if i have value a url - but works if i have the .swf locally.